# Are these bones correct for a simple model?

Tags: armature, bones

I've been making a low-poly model for my game, and I'm not very experienced with 3D modelling. Are these bones near the top of the model in the right place? I spawned the rig using rigify and positioned them the best I could

[image: Low-poly blender model]

I also wasn't sure about the "shoulder" bones, since they've been spawned in the clavicle.
Here is the file (and the .blend1) in a zip if it helps https://drive.google.com/file/d/129AjhQ-FKjjefdGwjQMd9sU3vkCcAM9h/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have several bones for the spine, for the neck or for the hand, the mesh is not subdivided on these parts, so you either need more topology on these parts, or remove the useless bones, depending on if you need them to bend or not. Try to align the bones head to the edges of your mesh. For the shoulder bones, you could stick the head to the top spine bone (and the tail to the arm's head), it should not change anything. Also you'll have to give IK constraints to some of your bones and create their IK controllers, it's easier to move the limbs with IKs.

Comment: Though when using rigify, make sure you don't delete bones needed for generating the rig. Check the manual : [Rigify — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html)

Comment: oh ok i forgot that, i don't know enough about rigify

Comment: Also see the [Bone Positioning Guide — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/bone_positioning.html)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that you needed to split the mesh where it needs to bend, I just assumed that it made like artificial topology when the armature bends the mesh, and if IK makes it easier to animate I'll have to try that, thanks.

Comment: @L0Lock what does the rig do? I've never used it, I just put the metarigged models straight into unity

Comment: I didn't mean split the mesh, just make sure that you have a topology that will be able to bend (a series of edge loops)

Comment: Sorry yes I meant that, I worded it poorly

Comment: The metarig is a placement tool to generate the actual animation rig, it isn't meant to be used as a rig. I will not make a better job at explaining it than the docs, so feel free to have a look at [Rigify — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

As a foreword, do understand that the best source to learn Rigify is its manual: [Rigify — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html).
Specifically, **if you want to use the metarig correctly, you should follow the [Bone Positioning Guide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/bone_positioning.html)**, basically to the letter. If you have troubles following that, I invite you to post a new topic describing the specific issues you encounter then.

About your file specifically:

#### Character is out of scale

If you look at the dimensions of your character, the rig is already 7.53 meters high. As a comparison, the default rigify metarig is already 1.98m high, which is taller than 99.96% of the average 30 years old male from the United States.

[image: out of scale]

You might not worry about having accurate scales now, but make sure you are in the right scale in Unity at least. Because physics use real dimensions, and so does some parts of the rendering process.

#### What is the metarig and how to use it

Many users think of the *metarig* as an actual rig that they can use as is. But it really is just a temporary placement tool to generate the real animation rig with all the functions that makes your life better when animating. As the manual sais:

> Rigify stores all the information required to generate complex rig controls and mechanism in more simple armatures called “meta-rigs”.

If for some reason you really do not want the full rig, you do you, but then you should consider other tools that might do a better and simpler job at it, like [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/)'s automatic rigging.
As for the metarig, to be used as a rig, you should edit it heavily. Its bones are not made to perform as a rig to begin with. Depending your model, bones will need to be deleted, dissolved or added.

[image: example]

On the left side is your rig with the original metarig, on the right is a modified metarig where I quickly removed the unnecessary bones, dissolved (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> in edit mode) the bones in a chain where the character's model didn't have the geometry to support so many points of deformation.

On the left you have 50 bones, on the right you have 24. That means, lighter files, and fewer headaches when skinning or animating.